# Wordpress permalinks not redirecting in my new theme

Tags: wordpress

I hope you can help me. I'm using /%postname%/ as permalink structure.

In the default theme everything working fine but in the new theme, default link '?p=123' does not redirect to the 'Post Name' link, and both links are working at the same time.

To clarify further... www.myblog.com/?p=123 does not redirect to www.myblog.com/some-blog-post. Both links are working, but no redirects are applied. This problem only occurs when this specific theme is enabled.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Please edit your theme `function.php` and add following code.

**code:-**

```
add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'thmf_flush_rewrite_rules' );


function thmf_flush_rewrite_rules() {
     flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```